# Suffix for ordinal indicator

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, fibonacci

Any suggestions for providing the suffix for the numbers?

I'm working on providing the following output for my code:

Example

Enter an integer (1-46): 6
The 6th number in the Fibonacci sequence is: 8

Below is what I have completed thus far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Somethingpart2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Variable Declaration 
        int number;
        long Fibnumber;


        Boolean accepted, limit;

        //Beginning of user input for the Fibonacci sequence 
        System.out.print("Enter an integer (1-46): ");
        number = kbd.nextInt();

        Fibnumber = Math.round(Math.pow((1+Math.sqrt(5))/2, number) / Math.sqrt(5)); 
        accepted = number >= 1 && number <= 46;
        limit = number == Fibnumber;


        if (accepted) {
            do {
                System.out.println("The " + number +" number in the Fibonacci sequence is: "+Fibnumber);
                //if ())
                return;
            }
            while (limit);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Not a valid number.");
```

I'm thinking where the `//if ()` is located, I can come up with a way to use `.contains` or `indexOf` to help with, for example, if variable number contains 3 as the last digit, then apply "rd" right after the 3.

*******Updated******
The last issue I seem to be running into is the exception numbers: 11, 12 and 13.

How do you go about ensuring 11, 12, and 13 get overlooked within the following if statements below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Variable Declaration 
    int number;
    long Fibnumber;


    Boolean accepted, limit;

    //Beginning of user input for the Fibonacci sequence 
    System.out.print("Enter an integer (1-46): ");
    number = kbd.nextInt();

    Fibnumber = Math.round(Math.pow((1+Math.sqrt(5))/2, number) / Math.sqrt(5)); 
    accepted = number >= 1 && number <= 46;
    limit = number == Fibnumber;


    if (accepted) {
        do {
            //System.out.println("The " + number +" number in the Fibonacci sequence is: "+Fibnumber);
            if (number % 10 == 3 && number % 10 !=13)
                System.out.println("The "+ number+"rd number in the Fibonacci sequence is: "+ Fibnumber);
            else
                if (number % 10 == 2 && number % 10 != 12)
                    System.out.println("The "+ number+ "nd number in the Fibonacci sequence is: " +Fibnumber);
                else
                    if (number % 10 == 1 && number % 10 != 11)
                        System.out.println("The "+ number+ "st number in the Fibonacci sequence is: " +Fibnumber);
                    else
                        System.out.println("The "+ number+ "th number in the Fibonacci sequence is: " +Fibnumber);
            return;
        }
        while (limit);
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Not a valid number.");
```

I thought I was going about it in the correct way. Is it the parentheses I'm messing up? I've  just tried different combinations with no success.

Comment: An easy way to isolate the last digit: just do `number % 10`.

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the example output above, right after my question.

Comment: @Blorgbeard. Appreciate the help. I can't believe how simple that was.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of changing the title to better reflect your actual question. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator. The ordinal indicator is exactly what you are asking about. "Suffix" is ambiguous. When I first read it, I thought you were asking about Java suffixes such as the "L" in 123L to indicate a `long` as opposed to an `int`. Also, your question is not really about Fibonacci numbers per se, although your application is.

Comment: Awesome. Appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Variable Declaration 
    int number;
    long Fibnumber;


    Boolean accepted, limit;

    //Beginning of user input for the Fibonacci sequence 
    System.out.print("Enter an integer (1-46): ");
    number = kbd.nextInt();

    System.out.println("");//Provides a space between the two print out statements within the program. 

    Fibnumber = Math.round(Math.pow((1+Math.sqrt(5))/2, number) / Math.sqrt(5)); 
    accepted = number >= 1 && number <= 46;
    limit = number == Fibnumber;


    if (accepted) {
        do {
            if (number % 10 == 3 && number !=13)
                System.out.println("The "+ number+"rd number in the Fibonacci sequence is: "+ Fibnumber);
            else
                if (number % 10 == 2 && number != 12)
                    System.out.println("The "+ number+ "nd number in the Fibonacci sequence is: " +Fibnumber);
                else
                    if (number % 10 == 1 && number != 11)
                        System.out.println("The "+ number+ "st number in the Fibonacci sequence is: " +Fibnumber);
                    else
                        System.out.println("The "+ number+ "th number in the Fibonacci sequence is: " +Fibnumber);
            return;
        }
        while (limit);
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Not a valid number.");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String getSuffix(long num) {
   long lastDigit = num % 10;

   switch (lastDigit) {
      case 0:
      case 4:
      case 5:
      case 6:
      case 7:
      case 8:
      case 9:
         return "th";

      case 1:
         return "st";

      case 2:
         return "nd";

      case 3:
         return "rd";

      default:
         assert false : "Shouldn't get here";
         return "";
   }
}
```